# Can deb packages from one machine be installed in another?

Tags: package, ubuntu-14.04, apt, deb

1. Install python-netinterfaces on machine1 using apt-get
2. Copy the python-interfaces deb package cached in /var/cache/apt/archive from machine to machine2
3. Change the /etc/apt/sources.list to point to the directory where the package is copied in machine2
4. Run teh following command
   sudo apt-get install python-interfaces

It inturn tries to install **python-chardet-whl** 
and I get the error
**warning: the following packages cannot be authenticated!**

If I install the python-chardlet-whl from command line it fails with the authentication error message. however, it passes with --force-yes message.

I searched in the web for solutions and tried some suggestions like apt-key update, but nothing worked. 
Is it possible to install package installed from one machine in another?

note: Both have same hardware and OS/other-software is installed is same

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure destination machine has same repository list as source machine?

```
apt-cache showpkg  python-chardet-whl
```

After adding repository to destination machine it would show you repository that package belongs to

Then you need to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To update the repository list, by doing this you problem should fix 
Also make sure that package does not need any dependency that is not installed on the system.